# Change values of object with values of second object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 files, one is an array of objects containing information about companies.
Here is part of the first one :

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "PGE Elektrownia Turów Spółka Akcyjna",
    "address": {
        "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 50.945669,
            "longitude": 14.90811
        },
        "countryId": 0,
        "cityId": 1,
        "street": "Młodych Energetyków 12",
        "zip": "59-916"
    },
    "filterData": {
        "specialization": 0,
        "tags": [
            4
        ]
    },
    "website": "https://elturow.pgegiek.pl/",
    "email": "elektrowniaturow.giekelt@gkpge.pl",
    "phoneNumber": "75 773 49 00",
    "isPaid": "NIE",
    "logoFile": "",
    "socialMedia": {
        "facebook": "",
        "linkedIn": ""
    }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Zakład Energetyki Cieplnej Sp. z o.o.",
    "address": {
        "coordinates": {
            "latitude": 51.264569,
            "longitude": 15.58923
        },
        "countryId": 0,
        "cityId": 2,
        "street": "Gałczyńskiego 51",
        "zip": "59-700"
    },
    "filterData": {
        "specialization": 0,
        "tags": [
            4
        ]
    },
    "website": "https://www.zec.boleslawiec.pl/",
    "email": "sekretariat@zec.boleslawiec.pl",
    "phoneNumber": "75 732 08 43",
    "isPaid": "NIE",
    "logoFile": "",
    "socialMedia": {
        "facebook": "",
        "linkedIn": ""
    }
}]
```

As You can see these objects contain values that are reference to ID's in second object here's sample of the second one that contains filters values

```
{"city": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Legnica",
        "searchMatchIds": [
            0,
            10,
            11,
            12,
        ],
        "childrenIds": []
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bogatynia",
        "searchMatchIds": [
            1
        ],
        "childrenIds": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bolesławiec",
        "searchMatchIds": [
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            60,
            63
        ],
        "childrenIds": []
    }],
 "tags": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "programowanie",
        "searchMatchIds": [
            0,
            13,
            48,
            53,
            54
        ],
        "childrenIds": []
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "web",
        "searchMatchIds": [
            0,
            10,
            18,
            20,
            45,
            52
        ],
        "childrenIds": []
    }]
}
```

And my question is what's the best way to replace Id values in companies for string values in filters
If you want better representation of these files here they are 1. https://pastebin.com/TAqW1cFw 2. https://pastebin.com/BQWtFyUx
I'm using Vue with vuex and already have both of these json files as states, just looking for function/logic that will be the most efficient in replacing values.

Comment: What's the logic required? Just match the numbers in the first file for the `id` in the second and pull in `name`? How does `searchMatchIds` fit in here?

Comment: searchMatchIds is used for another thing. I'm just looking for way to replace all ids with values from second object.

Comment: FYI - tags uses "4" but that id does not exist in your lookup data

Comment: You can look up the pastebins i posted, these are the full files. I just posted some part of it to show what I meant.

Comment: I cant access pastebin im afraid

Comment: Hmm I think they are set to be public, what about the raws? https://pastebin.com/raw/TAqW1cFw and https://pastebin.com/raw/BQWtFyUx

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in the `name` properties and it's efficiency you're after I might be tempted to pre-process the lookup data

```js
const lookupInput = {"city":[{"id":0,"name":"Legnica","searchMatchIds":[0,10,11,12],"childrenIds":[]},{"id":1,"name":"Bogatynia","searchMatchIds":[1],"childrenIds":[]},{"id":2,"name":"Bolesławiec","searchMatchIds":[2,3,4,5,60,63],"childrenIds":[]}],"tags":[{"id":0,"name":"programowanie","searchMatchIds":[0,13,48,53,54],"childrenIds":[]},{"id":1,"name":"web","searchMatchIds":[0,10,18,20,45,52],"childrenIds":[]}]}

const lookups = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(lookupInput).map( 
  ([key, data]) => ([key, data.reduce( (acc,i) => ({...acc, [i.id]: i.name}),{})])
));

console.log(lookups);
```

Then it just becomes a case of procesing your main input data and replacing the numbers with the names from the lookup data above

```js
const lookupInput = {"city":[{"id":0,"name":"Legnica","searchMatchIds":[0,10,11,12],"childrenIds":[]},{"id":1,"name":"Bogatynia","searchMatchIds":[1],"childrenIds":[]},{"id":2,"name":"Bolesławiec","searchMatchIds":[2,3,4,5,60,63],"childrenIds":[]}],"tags":[{"id":0,"name":"programowanie","searchMatchIds":[0,13,48,53,54],"childrenIds":[]},{"id":1,"name":"web","searchMatchIds":[0,10,18,20,45,52],"childrenIds":[]}]}

const lookups = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(lookupInput).map( 
  ([key, data]) => ([key, data.reduce( (acc,i) => ({...acc, [i.id]: i.name}),{})])
));

const input = [{"id":1,"name":"PGE Elektrownia Turów Spółka Akcyjna","address":{"coordinates":{"latitude":50.945669,"longitude":14.90811},"countryId":0,"cityId":1,"street":"Młodych Energetyków 12","zip":"59-916"},"filterData":{"specialization":0,"tags":[4]},"website":"https://elturow.pgegiek.pl/","email":"elektrowniaturow.giekelt@gkpge.pl","phoneNumber":"75 773 49 00","isPaid":"NIE","logoFile":"","socialMedia":{"facebook":"","linkedIn":""}},{"id":2,"name":"Zakład Energetyki Cieplnej Sp. z o.o.","address":{"coordinates":{"latitude":51.264569,"longitude":15.58923},"countryId":0,"cityId":2,"street":"Gałczyńskiego 51","zip":"59-700"},"filterData":{"specialization":0,"tags":[4]},"website":"https://www.zec.boleslawiec.pl/","email":"sekretariat@zec.boleslawiec.pl","phoneNumber":"75 732 08 43","isPaid":"NIE","logoFile":"","socialMedia":{"facebook":"","linkedIn":""}}]

const result = input.map(i => ({
  ...i,
  address: {
     ...i.address,
     cityName: lookups.city[i.address.cityId],
     
  }  ,
  filterData: {
        ...i.filterData,
        tags: i.filterData.tags.map(t => lookups.tags[t])
     }
}));

console.log(result);
```

Note: The above replace all tags with `undefined` but that is because your lookup data does not have the right id (`4`) - if it did then it should work.

Comment: Yeah, it does not have right id, because i just pasted a part of it. Thanks I will try it out!